# AFNetworking Certificate Pinning UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking UIWebView category and I was wondering if there is any way to load a url with certificate pinning check.

Best Regards,
fnxpt

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, no I had to implement NSURLConnection in order to validate the certificates

Answer (score 2):

`UIWebView` does not expose any direct API to that, but it can still be implemented using `NSURLProtocol`, which gives you the ability to validate the certificate of all outgoing network requests. It does take a lot of work though, and a better solution is to use `WKWebView`, which provides an explicit way of doing pinning via the `WKNavigationDelegate`'s [`webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html).

There are more details in the "Pinning in Webviews" section of this article: https://datatheorem.github.io/TrustKit/getting-started.html and it's also a library for implement public key pinning in iOS Apps.